# Как работают крупные проекты, которые используют несколько серверов?

Tags: сервер

Никогда не задумывался как работают проекты, которые используют несколько серверов.
Я нарисовал схемку (на ней все указано, но не знаю, верно ли). Если не верно, можете поправить или покидать статей на эту тему.

[image: схемка]

Comment: Читай на здоровье: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8 
https://www.servers.ru/knowledge/load-balancing/what-is-load-balancing-and-how-it-works https://habr.com/ru/company/selectel/blog/250201/

Comment: У каждого проекта всё индивидуально, а нарисованная вами схема далеко не самая оптимальная

Comment: @andreymal я понимаю, это первое , что пришло в голову

Comment: Читайте в сторону haproxy, и вангую вы про web интересуетесь. Есть еще сервера хранения данных (ceph) сервера передачи контента на libtorrent, сервера каширования данных, сервера кластеров бд, сервера VOIP,   сервера распределенной vpn...